# jQuery move's the div after element type change

Tags: jquery, css, forms

I have some jQuery code that changes the type of the input from text to password and clear's the default value which is "Your password.".

The problem is that i have a submit button under the input and it move's down every time i click on this input, i have tried some variations and when i remove `this.type` everything is ok, how can i fix it?

```
        $('input[name="password"]').focus(function() {
        this.type = 'password';
    if (this.value == this.defaultValue){
        this.value = '';
    }
    if(this.value != this.defaultValue){
        this.select();
    }
});
```

Comment: It's worth noting that IE won't allow you to change the `type` of an input after it's created...so you may want to re-think the whole approach here, as this is more of a secondary problem once you look at it from that angle.

Comment: hmm, do you have any good suggestions on how to show a text like "Password" on a password type field before it's clicked?

Comment: There are some simple plugins for this, basically they all hinge around a styled `<span>` or `<div>` absolutely positioned over the top of the input, [here's one popular lightweight example: labelOver](http://remysharp.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/03/label_over_example.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually [works](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen/XMJB7/1/) for me. The fun part was that `$('#theinput').attr('type', 'password')` didin't worked for me but `this.type = 'password'` worked.

I would suggest you to not write the input placeholder using the input value. In this case if a user choose to set his password     `password` then refocus the input the input will get cleared. I would use a `label` tag positioned inside the `input` using CSS that goes hidden or transparent when the input get the focus. It has two benfits, one is that `password = password` issue as I said and other is when the input get the focus the placeholder disappears that may make user confused

To achive this use this HTML, CSS and JavaScript(jQuery)

```
<label for="p">Password</label><input id="p" type="password" />
```

CSS

```
input{background:transparent}
label{margin-right:-65px;}
```

jQuery

```
$('#p').focus(function(){
$('label').css('color', '#ccc');
});

//hide the placeholder if something is typed
$('#p').keyup(function(){
    $(this).val() != '' ? $('label').hide() : $('label').show()
 });
```

See in action: http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen/EM7Pz/